# Working with arrays in AG Grid (Community) rows in Angular 9

Tags: angular, html-table, nested, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm currently trying to build an Angular 9 app with an AG-Grid table showing some data. 
The problem I have is that I am not able to find, how to work with nested arrays in AG Grid.

Example data object

```js
export class Office {
  uuid: string;
  employees: Employee[];
}

export class Employee {
  uuid: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  role: Role; // Role is an enum
  // ...
}
```

Now my problem is: I know how to write a cell renderer for AG Grid in Angular but I don't know, how I can make this thing filterable.

What will I need to do in the column definition for the employees?
If this is not possible in AG Grid Community: Is there another alternative then writing an own grid?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. You want to make something filterable?

Comment: the problem is  the array inside the office object: so what I want to do, is filter the office table based on employees role as an example

Comment: That's possible, the filtering is extremely flexible.

Comment: Ok now I know that.. but I don‘t know how to do that, I‘ve been searching the docs and Stack Overflow but I couldn‘t really find a way to do that

Comment: @HeavyTobi - is your problem displaying nested data or just filtering them? If you are able to display, then filtering should work out of the box unless you want to filter based on some other property

Comment: @PratikBhat It's the filtering. To display I easily can write a cell renderer but if I try to filter it just won't return any rows

Comment: @HeavyTobi - how complex is your employees column? have you tried valueGetter instead of cell renderer? valueGetter would solve your filtering problem